# one person, two phones, one text thread

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, macos

Is it possible for "Joe" to have two iphones with two different numbers and text Sally from both numbers, and when Sally receives Joe's texts they appear as one thread? In other words, Sally wouldn't know he has a second phone because it all appears as one thread. Thanks.

Comment: Sure if she had both of joes phone numbers and/or email address on the same contact.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. iMessage allows this with the following caveat.

1. Joe uses iPhone A to sign into iCloud with his account. The phone number for the first phone gets associated with the AppleID / iCloud account.
2. Joe uses iPhone B to sign into iCloud with the same account. Now both phone numbers are associated with the same Apple ID.

Now - set the "caller ID" in iMessage from both phones to be the same number (either can be chosen) and for iMessage recipients - all new messages started from iPhone A and iPhone B will be "from" one number.

This doesn't work for SMS since the carrier assigns the "correct" sender in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Add both of Joe's phone numbers to the text.  Most text message systems will support this.  So long as both people understand that Joe is using two numbers then there is no confusion, this doesn't meet the requirement of Sally remaining ignorant of two phones in use.

The other answer of using an AppleID only works if the two phones are linked by AppleID, and would mean Sally remains ignorant of two phones in use.

Sally putting both phone numbers in contact information should also make a text from either phone number appear to come from same person.  I don't know what happens to a reply, it may only go to phone that text was sent from.  That is unless Joe's phones are linked by AppleID.